# Masstransit error queue is consuming, but still is not empty

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am using Mastransit 3.5.0  with RabbitMq. If queue consumers throws exception, its is handled by default MoveExceptionToTransportFilter and moved to _error queue. For _error queue I have seperate consumer:
 Consume(ConsumeContext> context)

Behavior of Fault is rather different. Part of errors are handled and removed from _error queue, but part of error message still remain in error queue and do not consumed by this consumer. As I understand If I have Fault consumer then _error queue should be empty.

I can not find explanation, why errors are still in queue. Maybe because these faults were once consumed, but I cant find any indication in the headers or else where?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not correct.

1. You should not consume from the error queue. Error queue accumulates messages that crashed their consumers, for diagnostics purposes.
2. `Faut<T>` messages are published *in addition* to moving messages to the error queue. These two things are unrelated.
3. If you have a consumer of `Fault` or `Fault<T>` events, you just do that - consume these events. It has nothing to do with messages in the error queue.

Comment: Is there no way to properly consume the error queue, say in a second time, once the receiving hand has been corrected ?

Comment: You can use the Shovel plugin to move messages from the error queue back to the normal queue.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev This answer should be in the MassTransit docs. None of this is obvious to a first-time user.